# How to remove duplicate data from microsoft sql database(on the result only)

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

the column code has values that have duplicate on it , i do want to remove the duplicate of that row.

for example i want to remove the duplicates of column code as well the row that has duplicate on it. it doesent matter if the other column has duplicate but i do want to base it on the code column. what sql query can i use.? Thank you

[image]

[this is the table I am working to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Pqd.jpg)

as you can see there are isdeleted column that has value of 1 on them. I only want the recored with a value of 0 on them

[image]

here is a sample record, in here you can see that row 1 has a isdeleted value of 1, which mean that this record is deleted and i only need the row 2 of this code.

[image]

Comment: By "Microsoft SQL" - do you mean **SQL Server** (if so - please add a `sql-server` tag!), or are you referring to SQL in use in Microsoft Access? (`ms-access`)

Comment: What is your logic for deciding which of several rows to keep and which to delete?

Comment: You will need to add additional predicates to your where clause on data that makes each row you want to delete unique. Depending on how your data is structured you could potentially use a RANK function in a sub query of a delete statement so each row with a rank greater than 1 could be deleted. There are many ways to solve this and it all depends on the data in your table.

Comment: its for SQL server, my bad. I do want an output on which will remove the duplicates on the column code and remain only the row of it that is sorted by most current year from the effectivedatefrom column. heres the sample table. hope you guys can help me because there are thousands of duplicates on this table . I only want the remove the duplicates and remain only the unique row using the effectivedate from table . I didnt mean to delete the data, just a query that will show that sorted output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the windowing function [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to single out the last entry per `code` like in:

```
SELECT code, shortdesc, longdesc, isobsolete, effectivefromdate 
FROM (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY effectivefromdate DESC) AS rn, * 
 FROM CodingSuite_STG 
 WHERE isobsolete=1 AND isdeleted=0 
) AS cs
WHERE rn=1 
ORDER BY effectivefromdate
```

**Explanation:**

Core of the operation is a "sub-query". That is a "table-like" expression generated by having a `SELECT` clause surrounded by parentheses and followed by a table name like:

```
( SELECT * FROM CodingSuite_STG WHERE iobsolete=1 ) AS cs
```

For the outer `SELECT` it will appear like a table with the name "cs".

Within this sub-query I placed a special function (a "window function") consisting of two parts:

```
ROWN_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY code ORDER BY effectivefromdate DESC) AS rn
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function returns a sequential number for a certain "window" of records defined by the immediately following `OVER ( ... )` clause. The `PARTITION BY` inside it defines a group division scheme (similar to `GROUP BY`), so the row numbers start from `1` for each partitioned group. `ORDER BY` determines the numbering order within each group. So, with entries having the same `code` value `ROW_NUMBER()` will supply the number sequence `1, 2, 3...` for each record, with `1` being assigned to the record with the highest value of `effectivefromdate` because of `ORDER BY effectivefromdate DESC`.

All we need to do in the outer `SELECT` clause is to pick up those records from the sub-query `cs` that have an `rn`-value of `1` and we're done!

Comment: Hi Carsten , i’ll try this later and i will give you an update . hope you can help me on this. i would appreciate it. i will post here the extracted database later . Thank you

Comment: Just added "`DESC`" to the `order by` clause - as I said: "untested"  ... ;-)

Comment: Hello, i tried this query, will this query get the result for both isobsolete value that has 1 and 0?

Comment: Just added the `iobsolote=1`condition. Now it is more focused.

Comment: Hello , i do get the output that i want , thank you very much , would you kind enough to explain the query for me? sorry I'm new to SQL. so I could understand how this SQL query works .Thank you very much

Comment: Hello Carsten, I did not notice that i need to sort it also with the column isdeleted which has a value of 1 for deleted and 0 for not deleted.  I only want the records with 0 isdeleted values on it , can you help me to we edit this query to add that sorting ? thank you

Comment: Well, that should be easy to accommodate. I just added `AND isdeleted=0` into the Where clause of the subquery, which should do the job.

Comment: yeah I tried that , but the codes that has a isdeleted value of 1 on them is now gone from the list. is theres a way that I can get the row 2 of that particular column? where the row 2 has isdeleted value 0?

Comment: Well, if you still want to _see_ those recorde, but you want to apply a sort-order then you should sort by it using `ORDER BY effectivefromdate, isdeleted` and remove the `AND isdeleted=0` from the `WHERE`-clause again.

Comment: Hello Carsten, Thank you , its seem the query works just fine . Thank you for always helping me on this.

Comment: Hi @johndenverabella, I am glad I was able to help you! If you _really_ want to thank me, you could simply "accept" my answer.  Accepting an answer marks the question as "answered" and signals to other SO visitors that it won't require further attention.  ;-)